# Ambiguous overload on function pointer and std::function

Tags: c++11

```
#include <functional>

void foo(std::function<void()> f) { f(); }
void foo(void (*f)()) { f(); }

int main ()
{
  foo( [](){} );
}
```

VS compiles, gcc and clang complain about ambiguous overload. Who's right? The lambda is supposed to be of a class type, so there should not be any conversion between it and a function pointer. Thus VS appears to be right, against all odds. But perhaps I'm missing something.

Is there a simple way to disambiguate the call, apart from casting the lambda to either type?

Comment: Lambdas that don't capture anything (empty `[]`) *are* implicitly convertible to a function pointer of the same signature. VS (at least the version you use) does not implement this yet.

Comment: @JohannesD OK found this mentioned in 5.1.2/6. Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You can try disambiguating this ambiguity with `f( +[](){} );`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb - what does the `+` do? Where in the standard is this mentioned please?

Comment: @lori i recommend a new question for that

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb fair enough, thanks! Asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822131/resolving-ambiguous-overload-on-function-pointer-and-stdfunction-for-a-lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-capturing lambdas have an implicit conversion to a function pointer with the same signature. This is specified in chapter 5.1.2 paragraph 6:

> The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a
>   public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer
>   to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure
>   type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion
>   function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has
>   the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

Answer (score 4):

A lambda creates an anonymous and unspecified object that can be called, it's neither a function pointer nor a `std::function` object but can be used as both a function pointer and a `std::function` object, giving you the ambiguous overload error. I would say that VS is wrong.

Also, since a function pointer can be used to create a `std::function` object, I would say that using an overload that takes a function pointer is not needed if you already have a function taking a `std::function` argument.

Comment: The standard says: *The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion
_class type_*. The function pointer overload is more efficient as `std::function` involves all kinds of overhead (not significant in my particular case, but on principle I should not be forced to pay this cost).

Comment: @n.m - Whether it's a class type or not bears no relevance here - conversions between class types and between a class type and a builtin type are equal in the eyes of the overload resolution algorithm. Adding a special case just for the sake of lambdas would be a needless complication.

Comment: @JohannesD - *Why* is there a conversion between this particular class type and the function pointer type? Does the standard explicitly mention such a conversion?

Comment: @n.m. - Because it's useful. The standard specifies this in 5.1.2/6:

*The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture
has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function
that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.*