# Type conversion for lambda C++

Tags: c++, function, lambda, type-conversion

Is it possible to pass a lambda function as a function of some type?

For example, I have

```
typedef double(*Function)(int, double);
```

How can I convert a lambda function to the type?

Comment: It makes sense only for lambdas without closed values

Comment: Why do you use `typedef` in this day and age?

Comment: See [Passing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28746744/1708801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of a plain function pointer. This would allow to hold lambdas even when they have captures:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<double(int, double)> Function;

int main()
{
    Function f;
    int i = 4;
    f = [=](int l, double d){ return i*l*d; };
    std::cout << f(2, 3);
}
```

[[Live Demo]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10e1f02bb99af458)

Answer (score 7):

For a stateless lambda, this conversion is available implicitly:

```
Function f = [](int, double) -> double {};
```

If you just want to convert the lambda expression itself, you can use the unary `+` operator to achieve this:

```
auto* p = +[](int, double) -> double {};   // p is of type double(*)(int, double)
```

A lambda with a capture offers no such conversion, since it is not semantically equivalent to a (stateless) function (this applies even to the case of a default capture that doesn't end up capturing anything).

Comment: _"unary + operator"_ That's great! (As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283731/a-function-definition-is-not-allowed-here-before-token#comment79533605_46283731) there are still white spots to explore on the maps).

Comment: @user0042 - It is great. But sadly, a certain mainstream compiler, that shall remain unnamed, [still chokes on it](http://rextester.com/BQND42154).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822241/801894 for a deeper explanation of the unary + option.