# What is the different between +[](){}; and (+[](){}); and why the expression is valid

Tags: c++, lambda

As the title stated. The code is compiled using GNU c++2a

```
int main(){
  (+[](){});
  return 0;
}
```

Compiles fine.
However, the following code generates `warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]`

```
int main(){
  +[](){};
  return 0;
}
```

Further question is: my understanding about the expression `[](){}` is, it returns an r-value object `std::function<void()>`. While, I don't know there is a unary operator `+`, when the `+` applies on any r-value, should it be a compile error generated? Or maybe because of the operator precedence, the expression is interpreted in another way?

Comment: For the "+" see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822131/resolving-ambiguous-overload-on-function-pointer-and-stdfunction-for-a-lambda

Comment: "it returns an r-value object `std::function<void()>`" - no, it evaluates to an implementation-defined type (*"unnamed non-union class type — called the closure type"*), which can be used to construct a `std::function<void()>` (or assigned to one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> {} is, it returns an r-value object std::function<void()>

No, it creates a lambda/closure which is its own kind of thing.   There are cases when that is turned into a `std::function`, but what you're actually getting is much more similar to a functor (a class that implements `operator()`) than a `std::function` - which is a type-erased holder for things which can be called.

The `+` sign forces the closure to be turned into a function pointer (because that's the only thing thats "easy" to convert to which can have a unary + applied to it), which when wrapped in `()` "uses" the pointer value in a list context.   Without that, you compute a function pointer but then discard it immediately.  It's telling you that your `+` sign is silly.