# How to create a function that takes both function pointers and lambda as arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-pointers, function-templates

I have the following class who has a method called `errorHandler` that needs to use several different callbacks:

```
class IOPin;
class IOPinHandler
{
    IOPinHandler();
    virtual ~IOPinHandler();

    static bool ptrFun(IOPinHandler&) { return true; };

    template<typename T>
    bool init(IOPin& obj, const T& param);

    template<typename HandlerReturn = void, typename ...Args>
    HandlerReturn errorHandler(const GpioStatusCode& code, HandlerReturn(*callback)(IOPinHandler& obj, const Args&...), const Args&... args);

    // Added this overload to support passing lambdas as arguments, 
    // however does not seems to be called
    template<typename HandlerReturn = void, typename ...Args>
    HandlerReturn errorHandler(const GpioStatusCode& code, const std::function<HandlerReturn(IOPinHandler&, const Args&...)>& callback, Args&... args);
};
```

I can use the following:

```
return errorHandler(GpioStatusCode::wrongArgumentsError, &IOPinHandler::ptrFun);
```

And the code compiles successfully and runs as I expect it to do.

---

I can also use pass a lambda function in the following way:

```
auto fix = [](IOPinHandler& obj) -> bool 
{
    return true; 
};
return errorHandler(GpioStatusCode::wrongArgumentsError, static_cast<bool(*)(IOPinHandler&)>(fix));
```

This way, the code also compiles and runs successfully.

---

However, if I add capture to the lambda function, the code won't compile:

```
auto fix = [&](IOPinHandler& obj) -> bool 
{
    return true; 
};
return errorHandler(GpioStatusCode::wrongArgumentsError, fix);
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'IOPinHandler::errorHandler(GpioStatusCode, IOPinHandler::init<GpioMode>::<lambda(IOPinHandler&)>&)'
   12 |         return errorHandler(GpioStatusCode::wrongArgumentsError, fix);
```

I thought that adding:

```
template<typename HandlerReturn = void, typename ...Args>
HandlerReturn errorHandler(const GpioStatusCode& code, const std::function<HandlerReturn(IOPinHandler&, const Args&...)>& callback, Args&... args);
```

Would match the template instantiation for receiving the lambda function as argument, but the fact that I have to cast the lambda without capture and that the lambda with capture does not work either, kinda suggest to me that only the first definition or "`errorHandler`" is being invoked.

Is my reasoning right?
How could I get pass this?

---

**Edit**: Full code.

```
#include <functional>

class IOPin;

class IOPinHandler
{

    public:
        template<typename ...T>
        IOPinHandler(const T&... args);
        virtual ~IOPinHandler(); 

        static bool ptrFun(IOPinHandler&);

        template<typename T>
        bool init(const T& param);

        template<typename HandlerReturn = void, typename ...Args>
        HandlerReturn errorHandler(const int& code, HandlerReturn(*callback)(IOPinHandler& obj, const Args&...), const Args&... args);

        // Added this overload to support passing lambdas as arguments, 
        // however does not seems to be called
        template<typename HandlerReturn = void, typename ...Args>
        HandlerReturn errorHandler(const int& code, const std::function<HandlerReturn(IOPinHandler&, const Args&...)>& callback, Args&... args);
};

template<typename ...T>
IOPinHandler::IOPinHandler(const T&... args)
{
    (init(args),...);
}

bool IOPinHandler::ptrFun(IOPinHandler&)
{
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
bool IOPinHandler::init(const T& param)
{
    // Compiles with no problem
    // return errorHandler(1, &IOPinHandler::ptrFun); 

    // Compiles with no problem
    // auto fix = [](IOPinHandler& obj) -> bool 
    // {
    //    return true; 
    // };
    // return errorHandler(1, static_cast<bool(*)(IOPinHandler&)>(fix));

    // Does not compiles
    auto fix = [&](IOPinHandler& obj) -> bool 
    {
        return true; 
    };
    return errorHandler(1, fix);    
}

int main(void)
{
    IOPinHandler a(1,'c',true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what `std::function` is for, and the shown code makes use of it. Unfortunately, the disjointed code snippets seem to be too scattered, and are all over the place in order to see a clear picture. Can you [edit] your question and present a single, concise, [mre] that demonstrates your question?

Comment: FYI, in the non-capturing example, `static_cast<bool(*)(IOPinHandler&)>(fix)` can be simplified to just `+fix`, see [Resolving ambiguous overload on function pointer and std::function for a lambda using + (unary plus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822131/). Of course, `std::function` handles many different kinds of callables, including lambdas and function pointers, so you don't really need the function-pointer overload of `errorHandler()` to begin with.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. I just added a minimal reproducible example. Thanks for making me realize about that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. I just removed the const and refference from the argument. the declaration is now:  "HandlerReturn errorHandler(const GpioStatusCode& code, std::function<HandlerReturn(IOPinHandler&, const Args&...)> callback, Args&... args);". Still fails to compile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you don't need any member function overload or even `std::function`.

You can make the `Callable` as template parameter and let the compiler deduce the type of it for you.

```
template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
auto errorHandler(const GpioStatusCode& code, Callable callback, Args&&... args)
  // -> decltype(callback(args...))---> if compiler does not support C++14 or later
{
    // if needed within the function body
    using HandlerReturn = decltype(callback(args...)); 
    // ... do something
    return callback(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eTGETETcv)